# Rectangle detection with Hough transform

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, hough-transform

I'm trying to implement rectangle detection using the [Hough transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform), based on 
[this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.59.4239&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

I programmed it using Matlab, but after the detection of parallel pair lines and orthogonal pairs, I must detect the intersection of these pairs. My question is about the quality of the two line intersection in Hough space.

I found the intersection points by solving four equation systems. Do these intersection points lie in cartesian or polar coordinate space?

Comment: Can you provide more details?

Comment: No document with DOI "10.1.1.59.4239"
The supplied document identifier does not match
any document in our repository.

The DOI you requested --

10.1.1.59.4239

-- cannot be found in the Handle System.

Comment: The cited paper and the OP are lost. Should we close this one?

Comment: Can you please pate your code in pastebin and put a link here.

Answer (score 7):

For those of you wondering about the paper, it's:

*Rectangle Detection based on a Windowed Hough Transform* by Cláudio Rosito Jung and Rodrigo Schramm.

Now according to the paper, the intersection points are expressed as polar coordinates, obviously you implementation may be different (the only way to tell is to show us your code).

Assuming you are being consistent with his notation, your peaks should be expressed as:

[image: Peaks]

You must then perform peak paring given by equation (3) in section 4.3 or

[image: equation 3]

where [image: T_theta] represents the angular threshold corresponding to parallel lines
and [image] is the normalized threshold corresponding to lines of similar length.

Comment: It should be \delta\rho= |\rho_i + \rho_j | < T_\rho

Answer (score 4):

The accuracy of the Hough space should be dependent on two main factors.

The accumulator maps onto Hough Space. To loop through the accumulator array requires that the accumulator divide the Hough Space into a discrete grid.

The second factor in accuracy in Linear Hough Space is the location of the origin in the original image. Look for a moment at what happens if you do a sweep of \theta for any given change in \rho. Near the origin, one of these sweeps will cover far less pixels than a sweep out near the edges of the image. This has the consequence that near the edges of the image you need a much higher \rho \theta resolution in your accumulator to achieve the same level of accuracy when transforming back to Cartesian.

The problem with increasing the resolution of course is that you will need more computational power and memory to increase it. Also If you uniformly increase the accumulator resolution you have wasted resolution near the origin where it is not needed.

Some ideas to help with this.

1. place the origin right at the
   center of the image. as opposed to
   using the natural bottom left or top
   left of an image in code.
2. try using the closest image you can
   get to a square. the more elongated an
   image is for a given area the more
   pronounced the *resolution trap*
   becomes at the edges
3. Try dividing your image into 4/9/16
   etc different accumulators each with
   an origin in the center of that sub-image.
   It will require a little overhead to link
   the results of each accumulator together
   for rectangle detection, but it should help
   spread the resolution more evenly.
4. The ultimate solution would be to increase
   the resolution linearly depending on the
   distance from the origin. this can be achieved using the

---

```
    (x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = \rho^2
```

---

```
circle equation where
    - x,y are the current pixel
    - a,b are your chosen origin
    - \rho is the radius
once the radius is known adjust your accumulator
resolution accordingly. You will have to keep
track of the center of each \rho \theta bin.
for transforming back to Cartesian
```

Comment: do you have suggestions as to how to combine the accumulators after having analyzed two parts of the image? (your point 3)

Answer (score 1):

The link to the referenced paper does not work, but if you used the standard hough transform than the four intersection points will be expressed in cartesian coordinates. In fact, the four lines detected with the hough tranform will be expressed using the "normal parametrization":

```
rho = x cos(theta) + y sin(theta)
```

so you will have four pairs (rho_i, theta_i) that identifies your four lines. After checking for orthogonality (for example just by comparing the angles theta_i) you solve four equation system each of the form:

```
rho_j = x cos(theta_j) + y sin(theta_j)
rho_k = x cos(theta_k) + y sin(theta_k)
```

where x and y are the unknowns that represents the cartesian coordinates of the intersection point.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a mathematician.  I am willing to stand corrected...
From Hough 2) ... any line on the xy plane can be described as **p = x cos theta** + y sin theta. In this representation, p is the normal distance and theta is the normal angle of a straight line, ... In practical applications, the angles theta and distances p are quantized, and we obtain an array **C(p, theta)**.
from CRC standard math tables Analytic Geometry, Polar Coordinates in a Plane section ... 
Such an **ordered pair of numbers (r, theta)** are called polar coordinates of the point p.
Straight lines: let p = distance of line from O, w = counterclockwise angle from OX to the perpendicular through O to the line.  Normal form: **r cos(theta - w) = p**. 
From this I conclude that the points lie in polar coordinate space.