# Edge detection in Image processing

Tags: c#, image-processing, computer-vision, edge-detection

I need to get the rectangular counter of a sobel edge detected and threshold binary image, 
Does anyone know any suitable algorithm to get the count, which can be implemented using c sharp.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "rectangular counter".  Using a more descriptive title for your question would also help.

Comment: It is an image of a warehouse, I need to count out boxes in that warehouse by using edge detection techniques. The above mention image has been taken in top view, after Filtering by sobel and some pre processing steps, I able to get the edges of those boxes. Now I want to get the boxes count by identifying rectangular shape.

Comment: You've posted the same question three times already. If you're not happy with the answers you get, you should add more information to your question. What did you try already? What's your best idea, how well does it work, why doesn't it work? Post a typical image you want to inspect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count the number of objects in an Image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952165/count-the-number-of-objects-in-an-image)

Answer (score 2):

This has been discussed [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952165/count-the-number-of-objects-in-an-image).