# Python edge detection and curvature calculation

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision

I know the edge detection problem has been posted before (in Java: [Count the number of objects in an Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952165/count-the-number-of-objects-in-an-image), language independent: [Image edge detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540910/image-edge-detection)), but I want to know how to implement it in python.

I'm doing edge detection and curvature calculation around the edge on some simple shapes (binary shape with some noise). I know there are some wrapper for OpenCV, but not sure which one is better: pyopencv, pycv, pycvf?

Since I'm basically only doing this two tasks, I'm also not sure whether it would be faster to implement it by myself rather than using the library.

Comment: I would suggest downloading OpenCV from their [website](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) -- if you compile it using their instructions you automatically get the python wrapper (`import cv2`).

Comment: Also, have a look at `scipy.ndimage` http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html

Comment: News about the curvature computation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We have segmentation and edge detection algorithms in the actively developed `scikit-image` that you may find useful:

[Scikit Images Examples](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/)

Comment: Edge detection is cool. Will you implement curvature calculation?

Comment: @clwen How do you define curvature?  If you give me a paper or an example, we can give it a shot.

Answer (score 6):

You can easily achieve edge detection with scipy in python.

```
from scipy import ndimage
edge_horizont = ndimage.sobel(greyscale, 0)
edge_vertical = ndimage.sobel(greyscale, 1)
magnitude = np.hypot(edge_horizont, edge_vertical)
```

And here is an example of original image and the image after edge detection. [image]

In scikit-image, there is a [special page with explanations](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_canny.html) of how to do edge detection.

Answer (score 3):

There is a very simple way to find contours in python with scikit image. It's really just a couple line of code, like this:

```
    from skimage import measure
    contours = measure.find_contours(gimg, 0.8)
```

This returns the vector representation of the contour lines. In a separate array for each line. And it's also easy to decrease the number of points in a line by calculating an approximation. Here is a bit longer description with source code: [image vectorization with python](http://goo.gl/pc5h7)

Answer (score 2):

There are different edge detectors you can use: *Canny, Sobel, Laplacian, Scharr, Prewitt, Roberts*. You can do it with [OpenCV](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_canny/py_canny.html#canny-edge-detection-in-opencv):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('your_image.jpg', 0)

# Canny
edges_canny = cv2.Canny(img, 100, 100)

# Sobel
sobel_x = cv2.Sobel(img, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize=5)
sobel_y = cv2.Sobel(img, cv2.CV_64F, 0, 1, ksize=5)
edges_sobel = np.hypot(sobel_x, sobel_y)
edges_sobel *= 255.0 / np.max(edges_sobel)

# Laplacian
edges_laplacian = cv2.Laplacian(img, cv2.CV_64F)

# Scharr
schar_x = cv2.Scharr(img, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0)
schar_y = cv2.Scharr(img, cv2.CV_64F, 0, 1)
edges_scharr = np.hypot(schar_x, schar_y)
edges_scharr *= 255.0 / np.max(edges_scharr)
```

or with [scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.feature.html?highlight=canny#skimage.feature.canny):

```
import cv2
from skimage import feature, filters

img = cv2.imread('your_image.jpg', 0)

edges_canny = feature.canny(img) # Canny
edges_sobel = filters.sobel(img) # Sobel
edges_laplace = filters.laplace(img) # Laplacian
edges_scharr = filters.scharr(img) # Scharr
edges_prewitt = filters.prewitt(img) # Prewitt
edges_roberts = filters.roberts(img) # Roberts
```

**Canny edge detector** is probably the most commonly used and most effective method, but also the most complex. For more details on what is the difference between the mentioned methods check [this blog post](https://medium.com/@nikatsanka/comparing-edge-detection-methods-638a2919476e).

Comment: How to overlay the created edges back to the original images