# How to determine if a rectangle is well formed using open cv

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I am currently trying to determine if a rectangle is well formed such as having perfect corners and straight lines.

This is what I am currently doing now to detect a rectangle

```
 Mat image;
 image = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR); 
 cvtColor( image,image1, CV_BGR2GRAY );
 Canny( image1, canny_output,130, 200 );
 vector<Point> approx; 
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

findContours(canny_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, Point(0,0) );
     for (unsigned int i=0; i<contours.size(); i++){
           if((approx.size() == 4)){
                 cout<<"It is a rectangle"<<endl;
         }
    }
```

I can detect if it  is a rectangle but I am not sure how to detect that is a not a well formed rectangle like the images below.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you need a binary (well-formed / not) answer, or a measure of how rectangle-like your contour is?

Comment: @FrancescoCallari Maybe,that could be my solution

Comment: A binary well formed rectangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the test images are like the ones that you have posted here, you could try to use Hough Transform, firstly to detect the lines and the check if the lines are parallel. 
Try to have a look how to use **OpenCV Hough Transform implementation** on on [OpenCV here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html).

However I need more informations to clarify better the answer.
I also checked there are some others threads about this problem you could check the following:

- [Hough transformation vs Contour detection for Rectangle recognition with perspective projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260519/hough-transformation-vs-contour-detection-for-rectangle-recognition-with-perspec)
- [Rectangle detection with Hough transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364976/rectangle-detection-with-hough-transform).
- Moreover if you are familiar with research, have a look to [this paper](http://sibgrapi.sid.inpe.br/col/sid.inpe.br/banon/2004/08.03.17.14/doc/1.pdf).