# Detect with noisy background/object - OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

i'm trying to detect a card, but the problem is that sometimes the image is not good and has several backgrounds, like this:

Not well define edges

![Not well define edges][1]

Example background

![Example background][2]

I did this:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(11,11),0)

edg = cv2.Canny(gray, 10, 20)
contours,_ = cv2.findContours(edg.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cv2.drawContours(image,contours,-1,[0,255,0],2)

cv2.imshow('image',image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

But sometimes he detects other stuff, and not the card. Anyone has ideias how to solve this?
I've tried Object Detection with YOLO, but it's hard

Comment: Can you add original image ? So that can try some experiments

Comment: Done! You can find him in the end

Comment: Have you tried hough transform?

Comment: @FaroqAL-Tam can u show an example? Never heard of

Comment: Please look at this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364976/rectangle-detection-with-hough-transform

Answer (score 1):

first of all, note that, there are some condition like light condition and medium condition in take photo which if you can control them, the image processing section load will decreases. for example in your example image, you can put A4 white paper in the background to reduce small contours and so on(Of course it's impossible to change condition).

Well, i try on your test image with this code :

```
import cv2

rectKernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (8, 8))
sqKernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (17, 17))

img = cv2.imread('edge.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


gradX = cv2.Sobel(gray, ddepth=cv2.CV_32F, dx=1, dy=0,
    ksize=-1)

morph1 = cv2.morphologyEx(gradX, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, rectKernel)
morph2 = cv2.morphologyEx(morph1, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, sqKernel)


cv2.imshow("img",img)
cv2.imshow("gradx",gradX)
cv2.imshow("tophat",morph1)
cv2.imshow("tophat2",morph2)
cv2.waitKey()
```

here is the results:

[image: Sobel]
[image: morph1]
[image: morph2]

You can use contours and remove unwanted contours using contour properties : [Contour Properties](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d1/d32/tutorial_py_contour_properties.html)

Comment: that is a pseudo code which you can complete it. Main algorithm needs to see all photos and condition of your project. you can try yourself.

Comment: my code applied on Test1 image. in the final step you can add findcountour method and select contour with largest area and then mask it from original image.

Comment: please give real images for test.

Comment: Added 2 test images